# Using inside repository path in git textconv

Tags: git, path, attributes, config

I'd like to configure textconv in git for human-readable diffs of xml. And I'd like to keep the converter program inside the git repository. But ${GIT_WORK_TREE} doesn't seem to work:

.gitattributes

```
*.xts -text diff=XtsDiff
```

.git\config

```
[diff "XtsDiff"]
    textconv = ${GIT_WORK_TREE}/xmllint-1.0.exe
    cachetextconv = true
```

How to make textconv use a path inside the repository?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me on Windows with **ConEmu**, **cmd.exe** and **git-bash** (and I assume Linux):

```
[diff "XtsDiff"]
    textconv = `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/xmllint-1.0.exe
    cachetextconv = true
```